# How can you change the properties in the contenttemplate for a telerik RadButton?

Tags: vb.net, telerik, contenttemplate

I have the following code in my Telerik Radbutton:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Height="138px" Text="RadButton" Width="264px">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <img alt="testg" src="imagesprof.jpg" height="80" width="80" />
        <span class="btnText">Question 1</span>
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

---

I want to change the image and the background color in my code behind file.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a runat=server attribute so you can access it on the server (or use the Image server control).

Here is an example

```
        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Height="138px" Text="RadButton" Width="264px">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <img id="Img1" alt="testg" src="imagesprof.jpg" height="80" width="80" runat="server" />
                <span class="btnText">Question 1</span>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadButton>
```

and the server code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim img As HtmlImage = DirectCast(RadButton1.FindControl("Img1"), HtmlImage)
    img.Src = "the-new-url"
End Sub
```